# Why a segfault instead of privilege instruction error?

Tags: linux, performance, assembly, x86

I am trying to execute the privileged instruction `rdmsr` in user mode, and I expect to get some kind of privilege error, but I get a segfault instead. I have checked the `asm` and I am loading `0x186` into `ecx`, which is supposed to be `PERFEVTSEL0`, based on the [manual](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325384.pdf), page 1171.

**What is the cause of the segfault, and how can I modify the code below to fix it?**

I want to resolve this before hacking a kernel module, because I don't want this segfault to blow up my kernel.

Update: I am running on `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X3470`.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#include <sched.h>
#include <assert.h>

uint64_t
read_msr(int ecx)
{
    unsigned int a, d;
    __asm __volatile("rdmsr" : "=a"(a), "=d"(d) : "c"(ecx));
    return ((uint64_t)a) | (((uint64_t)d) << 32);
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    uint64_t start, end;
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    unsigned int c = 0x186;
    int i = 0;

    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
        CPU_SET(i, &cpuset);
        assert(sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpuset), &cpuset) == 0);

    printf("%lu\n", read_msr(c));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See the `dmesg` output, I think you'll see `traps`, which indicates you are trying to execute privilege instruction from usermode.

Comment: @rakib, output of dmesg: `general protection ip:4005d0 sp:7fff6dea4070 error:0`. I think that's what I needed to know. I will accept this answer, and ask the follow-up question separately.

Comment: Is it really needed, to ask this in separate question? You got what you want.

Comment: I am curious about this because as I dig into more `asm`, I want to understand more generally what kinds of things cause fake `segfaults`.

Answer (score 4):

The question I will try to answer: Why does the above code cause `SIGSEGV` instead of `SIGILL`, though the code has no memory error, but an illegal instruction (a privileged instruction called from non-privileged user pace)?

---

I would expect to get a `SIGILL` with `si_code` `ILL_PRVOPC` instead of a segfault, too. Your question is currently 3 years old and today, I stumbled upon the same behavior. I am disappointed too :-(

---

> What is the cause of the segfault

The cause seems to be that the Linux kernel code decides to send `SIGSEGV`. Here is the responsible function:
http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.9/source/arch/x86/kernel/traps.c#L487
Have a  look at the last line of the function.

In [your follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22292963/is-there-a-list-of-errors-will-show-up-as-segfaults-when-they-are-not-really), you got a list of other assembly instructions which get propagated as `SIGSEGV` to userspace though they are actually general protection faults. I found your question because I triggered the behavior with `cli`.

> and how can I modify the code below to fix it?

As of Linux kernel 4.9, I'm not aware of any reliable way to **distinguish** between a memory error (what I would expect to be a `SIGSEGV`) and a privileged instruction error from userspace.

There may be very hacky and unportable way to distibguish these cases. When a privileged instruction causes a `SIGSEGV`, the `siginfo_t` `si_code` is set to a value which is not directly listed in the `SIGSEGV` section of `man 2 sigaction`. The documented values are `SEGV_MAPERR`, `SEGV_ACCERR`, `SEGV_PKUERR`, but I get `SI_KERNEL` (0x80) on my system. According to the man page, `SI_KERNEL` is a code "which can be placed in si_code for any signal". In strace, you see `SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_addr=0}`. The responsible kernel code is [here](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.9/source/kernel/signal.c#L1032).

It would also be possible to grep `dmesg` for [this](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.9/source/arch/x86/kernel/traps.c#L518) string.

Please, never ever use those two methods to distinguish between GPF and memory error on a production system.

Specific solution for your code: Just don't run `rdmsr` from user space. But this answer is really unsatisfying if you are looking for a generic way to figure out why a program received a `SIGSEGV`.