# Is there a list of errors will show up as `segfaults` when they are not really related to memory access?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22292447/why-a-segfault-instead-of-privilege-instruction-error), I learned that attempting to run privileged instructions when not in ring 0 can cause what looks like a `segfault` in a user process, and I have two follow-up questions.

1. Is this true of all privileged instructions?
2. What other sorts of errors can cause a fake segfault but are not related to trying to read memory?

Comment: Read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read through the instruction set reference and see where `#GP` is listed for a non-memory issue. Incomplete list: `CLI`, `CLTS`, `HLT`, `IN`, `INT` (with an invalid vector), `INVD`, `INVLPG`, `IRET` (under circumstances), `LDMXCSR`(setting reserved bits), `LGDT`, `LIDT`, `LLDT`, `LMSW`, `LTR`, `MONITOR` (with `ECX != 0`), `MOV` (to `CRx` or `DRx`), `MWAIT` (with invalid `ECX`), `OUT`, `RDMSR`, `RDPMC`, `SWAPGS`, `SYSEXIT`, `SYSRET`, `WBINVD`, `WRMSR`, `XGETBV` (invalid `ECX`), `XRSTOR`, `XSETBV`